# searching for the winning id in bingo with SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, forms

I have created a bingo database (about 1000 id).
User coupons are sent to the form on the website and they are sent to the database.

```
ID  
num1-1  num2-1  num3-1  num4-1  num5-1  num6-1  num7-1  num8-1  num9-1  
num1-2  num2-2  num3-2  num4-2  num5-2  num6-2  num7-2  num8-2  num9-2  
num1-3  num2-3  num3-3  num4-3  num5-3  num6-3  num7-3  num8-3  num9-3
```

num"column"-"row"

the drawn numbers are transferred to a variable

How should I find that e.g. Id 261 has a match of 1 row or 2 rows or 3 rows (BINGO)

[image: sample playing card]

^sample playing card^

```
1
""  16  21  31  42  ""  60  ""  ""  
1   18  ""  33  ""  53  62  ""  ""  
2   ""  ""  38  ""  55  69  74  ""
```

e.t.c
^in SQL^

and  `var draw = 2,5,8,...,3,38,...,55,69,...,74`

and I want the message to be displayed, depending on the game mode, that id 1 has 1 row or 2 rows or 3 rows (BINGO)

Comment: Please, help us to help. Add sample data, what have you tried so far and expected output. It's not easy to understand that you create a database of about 1000 id and then you ask for the id 2137. Couldn't you simplify the question with 5 id's adding sample data?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp or 
https://www.php.net/preg_match

maybe this will help

Comment: ok now i added some data